# How to use java to download a video into a file?

Tags: java, video, download

I have a java program to download a video file via HTTP. But it just can download that webpage instead of video. I do not know the video file address. How could I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the video a simple file or a stream?

Comment: Ralph: I think it is a simple file. I do not download the streaming video, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the video url to download it. You can try to parse the html file to find it, but you need to know what you are looking for, is it `<video>` tag or `<object>` tag with flv file...

Comment: ok, thanks. but, for example, i want to download the video on this webpage, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nawMZ1pfWZs&feature=rec-LGOUT-real_rn-1r-2-HM". that is its URL. 

then i use protocol sniffer and find that there is a record which is "Requested URI: GET /generate_204?sparams=id.............." and its host domain. but the question is how i can use java to get this address

Comment: It's either in html or is loaded dynamically using javascript, not sure how youtube works, in either case you should find it somewhere earlier in the sniffer's recording, which might give you a clue how to calculate it programatically

Comment: Try downloading the file from youtube.com/v/{videoid}.